# Can packer use a vsphere template and extend it

Tags: packer

I have several images I build in packer for vsphere. You can think of these as base images, like a base linux, and base windows that have minimal required software installed. I then want to have additional images which will be built from the base template and have additional services installed for example

- **windows_template**: base image with some mandatory software
- **serviceA_template**: extends base template but with additional services for service A
- **serviceB_template**: extends base template but with additional services for service B

Is that possible in packer? that I can use a template name as the source instead of having to build again from ISo and install all the minimal software dependencies.

Comment: You would use the output artifact of the base template as the source, and not the template itself.

Comment: So in my packer builder for vsphere I have "convert_to_template: true" So this will store the template in vsphere for me. Then when using terraform to create a new VM I pass it the template name. I cant work out how with packer I can tell it I want to start with some prebuilt image thats a template and then modify it and save as a new template.

Comment: Oh you did not mean a Packer template. What builder are you using for your source?

Comment: Yeah sorry not packer template. So in packer I define my builder type as vsphere-iso, I have an ansible provisioner and the image builds fine. This gives me a base OS configured inline with our IT requirements and policy. I then want to build further images using effectivley this new vm template which is persisted in vsphere as the starting image which i can then deploy additional services and save service based images. These seems fairly easy for something like AWS AMI as I can just define the AMI to start from. But cant see an easy way for vsphere-iso to start from a prebuilt template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [vsphere-clone](https://www.packer.io/plugins/builders/vsphere/vsphere-clone) builder for this. After your base build produces a VSphere template, you can then use that output artifact as the source for the child Packer template build:

```
source "vsphere-clone" "this" {
  communicator        = "none"
  host                = "esxi-1.vsphere65.test"
  insecure_connection = "true"
  password            = "jetbrains"
  template            = "alpine" # output base build template specified here
  username            = "root"
  vcenter_server      = "vcenter.vsphere65.test"
  vm_name             = "alpine-clone-${local.timestamp}"
}
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for this, I had been looking only within the vsphere-iso builder for an option. This is gonna help fast track a lot of stuff for me now.